# Saving Excel file with a period in the middle of the file name

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing VBA to save an Excel file.

```vb
Sub savethisshit()

filepath = "C:\Users\***\****\***\AR\***\***by Customer\"
yr = Year(Date)
m = Month(Date) - 1
fac = Left(Sheets(2).Name, 3)

If fac = "EF " Then
    fac = "EF"
Else
    fac = fac
End If

If m < 10 Then
    mth = "0" & m
Else
    mth = m
End If

file = filepath & yr & "." & mth & " " & fac & " Vol by Customer.xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook().SaveAs file
End Sub
```

Whenever I try to execute this subroutine, it works, until `ActiveWorkbook().SaveAs file`.  I get a debug error.  However, if I run the macro through debug, it works.  I only get the error when I try to execute the macro.

Comment: What are the parentheses in `ActiveWorkbook()` for? I know they don't resolve any problem. So, perhaps they create one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.

1. The file extension disturbance by the period
2. And the current document is a document containing macros, but the storage target is a problem of warning due to a general Excel document.

I think it can be solved with the syntax **Application.DisplayAlerts = False.**

This warning message appears in the following cases: Two or more cells contain values, merge the cells, delete a sheet when there is a value on a sheet, etc. In your case, there is a period in the middle of the file name, and after that, it is recognized as a file extension, but a warning window pops up because it is different from the file format. If the macro-created document is saved as a general document, a warning window appears because the format does not match. However, this is something that gives the user a choice, not absolute. This can be used to let the user ignore the popping up of the warning window. You can use it for smooth progress of the program.

```
Sub savethisshit()
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim yr As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim fac As String
    Dim Ws As Workbook
    Dim file As String, mth As String
    
    filepath = "C:\Users\***\****\***\AR\***\***by Customer\"
    'filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    yr = Year(Date)
    m = Month(Date) - 1
    fac = Left(Sheets(2).Name, 3)

    If fac = "EF " Then
        fac = "EF"
    End If
    mth = Format(m, "0#")

    file = filepath & yr & "." & mth & " " & fac & " Vol by Customer.xlsx"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Ws.SaveAs Filename:=file, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works flawlessly now. I am still learning vba; I know there are things that can be coded more concisely. Seriously, thank you so much for the help. If you don't mind me asking, what is it about Application.DisplayAlerts that makes this code work? Also, thank you for updating the mth Format, for some reason, I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @TheMosesOfExcel, The content was too long, so it was posted in the body of the response without commenting.